# Convert moon's altitude to kilometers

Tags: php, altitude

I'm getting information about the moon's altitude from [yr.no's API](http://api.yr.no/weatherapi/sunrise/1.0/documentation) and they print the altitude as [50.0496753501172](http://api.yr.no/weatherapi/sunrise/1.0/?lat=59.379136;lon=13.500804;date=2013-05-17).

How can I convert that to kilometers; even if it is already in kilometers?

Comment: It is probably in `minutes` like the remaining GPS coords.

Comment: This is probably the moon's apparent altitude above the horizon, not the distance from the moon to the earth.

Comment: @shadyyx: Are you sure? The height above the sea (altitude) is not normally in minutes :)

Comment: maybe you mean angular elevation? the moon's "altitude" is ~350,000-400,000km

Comment: Can you show us the API call you're making?

Comment: @MarcB: I might be true that it's angular elevation yr.no's API mean.

Comment: @Jerryf: Not live because Windows 8 and WAMP Server doesn't corporate as fine as Windows 7 and WAMP :(

Comment: Is the altitude from transitType?

Comment: @Jerryf Did you click the link on 50.0496753501172?

Comment: Ahh, didn't see that :)

Comment: Looks like it is degrees from the horizon http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/astronomy.html?obj=moon&n=25

Comment: @MarcB you'd also need to define if you mean "distance from the Earth surface" (which is roughly constant) or "distance above the plane tangential to the Earth's gravitational isosurface at the observer's point (that is, above the idealized horizon)" (which is roughly proportional to the sine of the elevation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only `altitude` I see in the API response (below) is nested under the `<sun>` element, not `<moon>`. The API documentation you linked to refers to it as:

> The angle to the sun at solar noon is also given.

So what this `<noon altitude="50.0496753501172" />` really means is that, at noon, the sun will be about 50 degrees above the horizon. That's it. Nothing to do with the moon, nothing to do with distance.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense!